# How can the equation for a line in 2d space be represented as an array of three values?

Tags: bsp-tree

I am trying to understand the following function from [theparticle](http://www.theparticle.com/javadata2.html#Binary_Space_Partition_Trees) Supposedly, the function determines the equation of a line which is represented as an array of the coordinates for two points that lie on the line: [x1, y1, x2, y2]. The function that returns the equation is:

```
float [ ] getLineEquation( int [ ] line) {
    float [ ] equation = new float [3];
    int dx = line[2] - line[0];
    int dy = line[3] - line[1];
    equation[0] = -dy;
    equation[1] = dx;
    equation[2] = dy*line[0] - dx*line[1];
    return equation;
}
```

I don’t understand how the 3-element array that is returned by this function corresponds to the equation of a line. I appreciate any help that will let me understand what this function is doing.

Answer (score 2):

A line in 2D space can be described by y = ax + b or cx + dy + e = 0.
If you take the second form of the same equation than you can represent it as [c, d, e] which is your array of three elements.
I hope I understood well your question.